# Tomcat 8 getOpenSessions() not returning all sessions for end point?

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

I'm working on my first WebSocket app, and was surprised when code like this did not work consistently:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value="/msg/{owner}", encoders=MessageEncoder.class, decoders=MessageEncoder.class)
public class WebSocketListener {

    public WebSocketListener() {
    }

    @OnOpen
    public void open(Session session, @PathParam("owner") String owner) {
        if (session.getUserPrincipal() != null) {
            session.getUserProperties().put("owner", owner);
        }
        else {
            try {
                session.close(new CloseReason(CloseReason.CloseCodes.CANNOT_ACCEPT, "Not authorized"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    @OnClose
    public void close(Session session) {
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable error) {
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(final Session session, final Message message) {
        String owner = (String)session.getUserProperties().get("owner");
        for (Session s:session.getOpenSessions() {
            System.out.println(s);
            if (s.isOpen() && owner.equals(s.getUserProperties().get("owner"))) {
                s.getAsyncRemote().sendObject(message);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

What I observe when connecting to this end point from two clients and the same 'owner', is that sometimes both sessions are returned from getOpenSession(), but more often than not only that user's session is returned, as evidenced by the System.out.println. My workaround was to ditch using getOpenSessions by adding a static map to this class, adding the session to a list using the owner as the key, and just using that instead. But is this a known bug, I couldn't find anyone complaining about this from searching?

Comment: Hi did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem, tomcat 8.0.36, Centos7. getOpenSessions only ever returns the user session. Although when I test it on my localhost it works fine, although it is with a slightly earlier tomcat8 server ran thorough eclipse. Another thing different between the two set ups is that I have excluded the websocket and javaee-api jar from my .war file but I don't think that should make a difference

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be a bug in tomcat, I faced the same issue with embedded tomcat in Spring Boot, changing the server to Jetty resolved the issue. In Spring Docs, there is a section explaining how to switch the server: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-jetty-instead-of-tomcat