# Tomcat's interpretation of javax.websocket.Session#getOpenSessions

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

[`Session#getOpenSessions`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/Session.html#getOpenSessions--) of the Java WebSocket API is said to

> Return a copy of the Set of all the open web socket sessions that represent connections to the same endpoint to which this session represents a connection.

This is ambiguous, however, because *"endpoint"* could refer to either the unique endpoint instance represented by this `Session`, or it could refer to the endpoint class (more precisely the set of instances of the class). Each new connection creates a new instance of the class so that there is always exactly one `Session` associated with each instance (as I understand it). In the light of this, one would expect the first interpretation to be the wrong one.

Danny Coward, the author of the above linked documentation and [Java WebSocket Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DRC96W6) gives an example, in the book just mentioned, of how to use the method which supports the above hypothesis:

> As a reminder, each client
>   that is connected to this server endpoint is associated with a unique
>   WebSocket connection, each of which in turn is represented by a unique
>   Session instance. So this method is a very convenient way of listing all the
>   connected clients to this endpoint.

The way one expects it to work is indeed how it usually works, but Tomcat 7.0.63 changed this. There are some questions here regarding this issue such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38268369/tomcat-8-getopensessions-not-returning-all-sessions-for-end-point) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43686210/getopensessions-giving-empty-value), and there it is treated like a bug. It was [reported as a bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58223) in BugZilla as well, but refuted as intended behavior. Reading the [changelog for Tomcat 7.0.63](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html) we see the following:

> Session.getOpenSessions should return all sessions associated with a given endpoint instance, rather than all sessions from the endpoint class.

which causes a lot of confusion.

---

**My questions are hence:**

- Is this a mistake by the Tomcat team?
- What is the use of `getOpenSessions` now as there is only one `Session` per instance?
- Is there a workaround for this problem or must one simply stay away from Tomcat versions >= 7.0.63?

Comment: it is even more confusing what should happen in a clustered server: should this method return `Session`s from the given node only or also some remote proxies to `Session`s on other nodes?

Answer (score 1):

yes, this is a mistake by the Tomcat team. (I'm former maintenance lead of WebSocket spec). [Session#getOpenSessions](https://tyrus-project.github.io/apidocs-javax.websocket/1.1/javax/websocket/Session.html#getOpenSessions()) should return all open sessions to the same endpoint class.

Comment: how about in a clustered server? should it return `Session`s from the given node only or also some remote proxies to `Session`s on other nodes? Thanks!

Comment: ok, I've got at least partial answer from [RemoteSession javadoc](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/tyrus-project.github.io/apidocs/latest/org/glassfish/tyrus/core/cluster/RemoteSession.html).